# How to change the amperage output on the gpio pins to power a relay

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have been unable to find any documentation regarding using python to change the GPIO outputs, and was wondering whether there was any specific code i could use to change it or if there were any third party programs that allowed me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *change* the current of GPIO pin, that's not how it works.

If you want to know the maximum value of current for GPIO pins, [this article](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Raspberry/Understanding_Outputs.html) says it's 16mA per pin, with maximum of 51mA for all pins.